# Why is Marcus stronger than the other heart eater witches?

Tags: the-bastard-son-the-devil-himself

In *The Bastard Son and the Devil Himself*, Marcus Edge is treated as an almost unstoppable force of destruction, dubbed "the devil himself" by several people, who is sufficiently strong that he judges Soul as basically beneath his notice even after the  latter has perhaps ten or so abilities. To judge from the massacres attributed to Marcus and the abilities that he displays and that are described by Ceelia, he has perhaps a few dozen powers at most. He is so powerful that no one, except Soul when he starts showing signs of mental instability, even contemplates taking the fight to him, even with the advantage of numbers.

However, we know that the Ozanne heart eater witch was explicitly described as having *hundreds* of powers passed down by successive heart eating over the years, and from the description of Marcus's own mother, she would have had a similar quantity. All that, of course, on top of the usual Blood witch talent of healing ten times faster than Fairborn witches. No one hesitated to confront either of these witches, both of them were successfully killed, and indeed, the Ozanne matriarch died without using even a single one of her powers in the fight.

What makes Marcus so much more powerful or dangerous than the other heart eater witches?